# Mysql query unknown behavior

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I have the following query that I'm working on for a wordpress website:

```
Select
    posts_tender.ID AS tender_ID,
    tender_meta_user_ministry_tbl.meta_value,
    CONCAT('<a style="font-weight: bold;font-size: 15px;" href="'
          ,posts_tender.guid
          ,'" target="_blank">المزيد...</a>') AS tender_title_with_link_to_post,
    posts_tender.post_status AS tender_post_status,
    DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(tender_meta_tender_date_tbl.meta_value , '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i'), '%d/%m/%Y') AS tender_meta_tender_date,
    posts_tender.post_title AS tender_meta_tender_subject,
    tender_taxonomy_language_tbl.name AS tender_taxonomy_language,
    tender_taxonomy_tendercategory_tbl.name AS tender_taxonomy_tendercategory,
    tender_meta_tender_status_tbl.meta_value AS tender_meta_tender_status
FROM wp_posts AS posts_tender
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        (SELECT tender_meta_tender_date_tbl_posts.ID as id,
                meta_value, 
                meta_key  
         FROM wp_postmeta AS tender_meta_tender_date_tbl_postmeta 
         INNER JOIN wp_posts AS tender_meta_tender_date_tbl_posts  
           ON tender_meta_tender_date_tbl_postmeta.post_id = tender_meta_tender_date_tbl_posts.ID   
           AND tender_meta_tender_date_tbl_posts.post_type = 'tender'
        ) AS tender_meta_tender_date_tbl
  ON tender_meta_tender_date_tbl.meta_key = 'tender_date' 
  AND tender_meta_tender_date_tbl.id = posts_tender.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        (SELECT tender_meta_user_ministry_tbl_posts.ID as id, 
                meta_value, 
                meta_key  
         FROM wp_postmeta AS tender_meta_user_ministry_tbl_postmeta 
         INNER JOIN wp_posts AS tender_meta_user_ministry_tbl_posts   
           ON tender_meta_user_ministry_tbl_postmeta.post_id = tender_meta_user_ministry_tbl_posts.ID   
           AND tender_meta_user_ministry_tbl_posts.post_type = 'tender'
        ) AS tender_meta_user_ministry_tbl
  ON tender_meta_user_ministry_tbl.meta_key = 'user_ministry' 
  AND tender_meta_user_ministry_tbl.id = posts_tender.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        (SELECT name, 
                object_id as id 
         FROM wp_terms AS tender_taxonomy_language_tbl_terms 
         INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS tender_taxonomy_language_tbl_termtaxonomy 
           ON tender_taxonomy_language_tbl_termtaxonomy.term_id = tender_taxonomy_language_tbl_terms.term_id  
           AND tender_taxonomy_language_tbl_termtaxonomy.taxonomy = 'language' 
         INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships AS rel_tender_taxonomy_language_tbl  
           ON tender_taxonomy_language_tbl_termtaxonomy.term_taxonomy_id = rel_tender_taxonomy_language_tbl.term_taxonomy_id
        ) AS tender_taxonomy_language_tbl
  ON tender_taxonomy_language_tbl.ID = posts_tender.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN
        (SELECT name, 
                object_id as id,
                tender_taxonomy_tendercategory_tbl_terms.term_id AS tender_category_id 
         FROM wp_terms AS tender_taxonomy_tendercategory_tbl_terms 
         INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS tender_taxonomy_tendercategory_tbl_termtaxonomy 
           ON tender_taxonomy_tendercategory_tbl_termtaxonomy.term_id = tender_taxonomy_tendercategory_tbl_terms.term_id  
           AND tender_taxonomy_tendercategory_tbl_termtaxonomy.taxonomy = 'tendercategory' 
         INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships AS rel_tender_taxonomy_tendercategory_tbl  
            ON tender_taxonomy_tendercategory_tbl_termtaxonomy.term_taxonomy_id = rel_tender_taxonomy_tendercategory_tbl.term_taxonomy_id
        ) AS tender_taxonomy_tendercategory_tbl
  ON tender_taxonomy_tendercategory_tbl.ID = posts_tender.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        (SELECT tender_meta_tender_status_tbl_posts.ID as id, 
                meta_value,
                meta_key  
         FROM wp_postmeta AS tender_meta_tender_status_tbl_postmeta  
         INNER JOIN wp_posts AS tender_meta_tender_status_tbl_posts   
           ON tender_meta_tender_status_tbl_postmeta.post_id = tender_meta_tender_status_tbl_posts.ID   
           AND tender_meta_tender_status_tbl_posts.post_type = 'tender'
        ) AS tender_meta_tender_status_tbl
  ON tender_meta_tender_status_tbl.meta_key = 'tender_status' 
  AND tender_meta_tender_status_tbl.id = posts_tender.ID 
where  1=1
AND posts_tender.post_type = 'tender'
And posts_tender.post_status = 'publish'
And tender_taxonomy_language_tbl.name = 'العربية'
And (tender_meta_tender_status_tbl.meta_value is NULL 
  OR tender_meta_tender_status_tbl.meta_value = 0)
And SUBSTRING_INDEX(
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(
            tender_meta_user_ministry_tbl.meta_value,
            '\"', 
            -2), 
        '\"', 
        1) = Case 
               When (1103 = 0 Or 1103 = '' Or 1103= null Or 1103= 'null')
                 then 0
               else 1103 
             End
```

and the query is working fine on my local database, but after importing the database on a live environment, the query is returning no data.

After troubleshooting the issue, if I added the below where condition to the query, a record will return:

> **and posts_tender.ID =14261**

Does anyone have an idea on why is this happening?

Comment: http://www.sqlstyle.guide/

Comment: @tereško I didn't write the query but I'm trying to fix it, also this is a wordpress mysql database so all data that are returning are a result of multiple joins of two tables wp_posts and wp_postmeta

Comment: if i removed the condition (And tender_taxonomy_language_tbl.name = 'العربية') and changed (posts_tender.post_type = 'tender') to (posts_tender.post_type like '%tender'), the query will return result, knowing that the field posts_tender.post_type doesn't have any data before the "t" in "tender"

Comment: is it possible to be an encoding issue??

Comment: check table collation and character set, collation is used to compare the result, compare those with your local

Comment: What are the database versions on both the environments?